# Is there arbitrage?

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

> An economist writes a **1-period expectation model** for valuing options.
>   The model assumes that the stock starts at S and moves to $2S$ or 
>   $\frac{1}{2}S$ in 1 year's time with equal probability. Strike is equal to $K$
>
> Assume rates are zero.

I found that the value of the call option using the economist's model is  $$S-\frac{1}{2}K$$ and using the Binomial 1-period pricing model it is $$\frac{2}{3}S-\frac{1}{3}K$$

So we have 2 models

- 1-period binomial model
- 1-period expectation model

**Is there arbitrage between the two models? If so, how can we capture it?**

Comment: What binomial model are you looking at?  Of course if you make two different assumptions regarding the price action of the underlying you'll get different values for the call.  Worth noting:  your price for the call is only valid if $K≤2S$.

Comment: Single period binomial model is the one I am considering

Comment: Yes, but there are parameters attached to that.  How is it calibrated?  Do you set it to give the same forward?

Comment: Yes, I set it to give out $2S$ if stock goes up and $\frac{1}{2}S$ if it goes down, if that is what you mean. And I found the risk neutral probabilities to be $\frac{1}{3}$ when it goes up and $\frac{2}{3}$ when it goes down.

Comment: But that does not have the same forward, so of course the option has a different value.

Comment: The "economist" model you have contains a risk premium.  there's already a statistical arbitrage built in, since interest rates are $0$ but the stock is projected to increase in value. That risk premium is reflected in the pricing of both the forward and any other derivatives.

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand. You say that statistical arbitrage is built into the economist's model but how does this help us understand how to capture the arbitrage between the two models?

Comment: You can't.  There is no arbitrage.  This is the whole point of risk neutral pricing.  Even though investors demand risk premia, according to their private Utility functions (hence the economist model), if you assume the market to be arbitrage free (big assumption) then there is a risk neutral measure that prices derivatives correctly.  That's your binomial model here.  Of course, if you can get the economist to trade with you using their private Utility function, then you can simply sell them the forward.  Instant arbitrage!

Comment: Let me stress that last point:  the economist says he believes the fair forward price to be $\frac 12\times (2S+.5S)=\frac 54S$.  But rates are $0$ so in a normal market the forward must be $S$.  If the economist is willing to stand by their model you can sell the forward to them and buy the forward in the liquid market, and capture a riskless $\frac 14S$.  But I expect your economist would decline to honor their model in this way.

Comment: Where did you get that formula for the forward price?

Comment: What do you mean?  It's your model.  You told me the price at the end of the year was either going to be $2S$ or $.5S$ with equal probability.  I just read the expected value off of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, economists think in terms of risk premia. There's a concept in the economic branch of asset pricing, called "stochastic discount factor", which differentiates economists from mathematicians.
That being said, the question asks you to find the value of the option today. As an economist, you will attach 1/2 of the probability to each outcome; hence,

> Call Price Today = $\frac{1}{2}$ (Payoff from Call Price Up) + $\frac{1}{2}$ (Payoff from Call Price Down)

Bear in mind that the tree you construct for the stock is equivalent to the tree constructed for the calls.
Then, denote the payoff in the usual way, i.e. $max(S(1)-K, 0)$, which leads to the following:

> Payoff from Call Price Up = $max (2S-K, 0)$
>
> Payoff from Call Price Down = $max (0.5S-K, 0)$

Now, make the assumption that the strike price, $K$, is such that $$S(down) < K < S(up)$$ Therefore, the call that goes down will be OTM, namely will have a payoff of zero; while the other one, which is ITM,  will be worth $2S - K$.
Therefore, the economist will price the option as:

> $p(Call) = \frac{1}{2} * (2S - K) + \frac{1}{2} * (0)$

For a mathematician using risk-neutral pricing, things are slightly different. There's no need to know the actual probability as it is possible to construct synthetic ones. However, note that economics and mathematics are highly interlaced here. Risk-neutrality lies on important economic intuition too, which relies around risk aversion.
Hence, in the binomial tree, you simply calculate the risk-neutral probability as you did and find that:

> $p(Call) = \frac{1}{3} (2S-K) + \frac{2}{3} (0) $

Here comes the tricky part of the question. I think what is meant is that the 1-period expectation model presents a mis-pricing, which makes the price of the call overvalued. If you were an arbitrageur, you would know that because you calculated what the price of the call is using risk-neutrality. Hence, you would sell the overvalued call and buy the underlying. This strategy is known as "naked call strategy".

I hope this helps!

Comment: Or, along the lines suggested by lulu above, and in Waie's answer, the economist's mistake is in not including a risk premium in the option calculation.  If the interest rate is zero, and people are risk neutral, then a share of stock  is worth $1/2 2S +1/2 1/2 S= 5/4 S$ but  it is only selling for S.